# Use ng-repeat in a table cell

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to use ng-repeat in a table cell.

Below is the table I built using handlebar without using AngularJs:

[Table 1, without using AngularJs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L86T.png)

Below is the table I built using AngularJs:

[Table 2, using AngularJs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QlBO.png)

As you can see, in table 2, the books are not in the same line, making the table more "ugly". How can I list the books in the same line just like in table 1?

Below is my AngularJs code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="author in authors">
        <td>{{author.authorId}}</td>
        <td>{{author.authorName}}</td>
        <td><p data-ng-repeat="book in author.books">"{{book.title}}"</p></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-table" data-ng-click="showUpdateAuthorModal(author.authorId)">Update</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-table" data-ng-click="showDeleteAuthorModal(author.authorId)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

If I use "p" or "h" to nest ng-repeat, I get the same result with book titles shown in multiple lines. How can I list the books in the same line just like in table 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `<p>` tag is a block element. You can use an inline element like `<span>` to do what you want or add css rules to modify the default behavior of `<p>` in your table

```
<td><span data-ng-repeat="book in author.books">"{{book.title}}" </span></td>
```